# Google Analytics: historical data does not work but Real-Time data works

Tags: google-analytics

Our website has around 260,000 to 300,000 sessions each day. There had 4 days that the historical data is zero but Real-Time works correctly.

Here is a summary of what I know and have checked:

1. Real Time reporting is working.
2. GA reports no problems with tracking code, neither does tag manager.
3. We haven't changed any code and nothing has changed on the server apart from increased resources (CPU and RAM).
4. A subdomain on the same server with a different GA account is reporting fine, although this site has only a tiny fraction of the traffic on our main site.
5. I am not using a filtered view (and I have checked I am looking at today's date!).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Google Analytics takes 2 to 48 hours to process data coming in before it appears on reports other than "real-time."   You say you are looking at "today's date", but that may not have the data ready yet.   Do you also see the problem for two days ago or before?

Comment: Please also verify with GA Debugger that the hits are being sent, and to the correct property. Also, intraday data isn't a reliable indicator, so try to use (well) processed data (sometimes intraday data that does show up in your reports isn't accurate).